# Customising Syntax Highlighting in TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, highlighting, syntax

I'm wondering if there is any way to add new syntax highlighting patterns to TeXmaker.

I've been using TeXworks for years and I love that special characters `$` `&` `{` `[` etc. are highlighted differently form everything else. The rest of the Texworks editor is a little minimalist though and I've been thinking of changing to a more feature rich editor. In particular, I like the "structure" and code folding that TeXmaker offers.

In Texworks you can define custom syntax patterns by editing the `syntax-patterns.tex` file. Is there a similar thing hidden in TeXmaker somewhere? I've obviously found the custom syntax colouring menu in `Preferences > colour` but this has a very prescriptive set of categories with no option to highlight custom strings differently.

Alternatively, does anybody know of another editor which offers customisable or TeXworks-style syntax highlighting and code folding.

Failing that, TeXmaker is open source right? Does anybody know about how syntax highlighting is taken care of? Perhaps I could hack a solution implementing customisable syntax highlighting for TeXmaker.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Alternative, Texstudio

Comment: Why not contacting Texmaker to make this suggestion? https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/#contact

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [TexStudio](http://www.texstudio.org/). It's a feature rich fork of TeXmaker and has an extended syntax highlighting with more options than TeXmaker. It also has a custom highlighting section in the options, note that this is an [unfinished feature](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-the-custom-highlighting-work) though. But probably it will do the trick for you.